# How to transfer the ArrayList value from Script Assertion to Groovy Script test step?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm getting array of values from the XML data and I need to store that value in a custom property and then I have to make use of it in the Groovy script.

When I try to write a script like this:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )

def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText( messageExchange.response.responseContent ) 

if (results != null)
{
    List rowset = results?.ResultSet?.Row?.collect{"${it.OBJ_ID} ${it.REL_OBJ_ID} ${it.CUST_MODEL_CD} ${it.TYPE_CD}"}
    log.info(rowset)

    context.testCase.setPropertyValue("RowData", rowset)
}
```

I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) values: [RowData, [18144046 5276601 CI DRVD, 18144050 5276601 CI DRVD, ...]]
Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)
```

How can I transfer these values from **Script Assertion** to **Groovy Script** ?

Comment: summary and description do not seem to match. Why do you need to transfer from script assertion to groovy script step? what is the structure of test case?

Answer (score 0):

According to exception that is being thrown:

```
No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) values: [RowData, [18144046 5276601 CI DRVD, 18144050 5276601 CI DRVD, ...]]
Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)
```

`setPropertyValue` method expects two `String` parameters.

You can try serializing `rowset` list to JSON string and passing this string to `setPropertyValue`. Next, when you need to read it as list all you have to do is to deserialize this JSON string to a `List<String>` object. Here is how you can do serialization and deserialization using Groovy's classes `JsonOutput` and `JsonSlurper`:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

List<String> rowset = ['18144046 5276601 CI DRVD', '18144050 5276601 CI DRVD']

String json = JsonOutput.toJson(rowset)

List<String> fromJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

assert rowset == fromJson
```

Your updated part could look like this:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )

def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText( messageExchange.response.responseContent )

if (results != null)
{
    List rowset = results?.ResultSet?.Row?.collect{"${it.OBJ_ID} ${it.REL_OBJ_ID} ${it.CUST_MODEL_CD} ${it.TYPE_CD}"}
    log.info(rowset)

    context.testCase.setPropertyValue("RowData", groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(rowset))
}
```

And when you load the data later on you could do:

```
List<String> rowset = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("RowData"))
```

Hope it helps.